# Can electromagnetic waves with long wavelengths (1 kHz to 1 GHz) also be considered as Photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, interference, double-slit-experiment

Could we conduct the Double Slit Experiment with long wavelengths (e.g. frequencies between 1 kHz and 1 GHz) and still measure through which slit the wave/particle goes?

I am sure that the interference pattern will be visible, but very large, (a few kilometers between maxima) but can electromagnetic waves with long wavelengths also be considered as Photons/Particles?

Comment: 1GHz is a 0.3m wavelength, so the pattern is pretty compact. Diffraction of propagating radio signals at various frequencies is a well known phenomena in ham radio circles, although we don't arrange double slits but instead get impacted by buildings and mountains and whatnot...

Comment: The energy of any electromagnetic wave is quantized. The quanta are called photons. But I'm not aware of any single-photon detector available for frequencies below 1 GHz.